# Two queries usually run fast but get slow when joined

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, mariadb, optimization, query-performance

There are those 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `media` (
  `mid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `media_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `performed_by` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mid` (`mid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `media_id` (`user`,`media_id`),
  KEY `user` (`user`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `performed_by` (`performed_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1687306 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `media_resources_used` (
  `muid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `media_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `resources_used` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`muid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `media_id` (`media_id`),
  KEY `media_id_2` (`media_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1507815;
```

They're connected by `media_id`. One row from media_resources_used can have n rows at media.

They both have over 1 million entries.

media_resources_used is used to determine what resources have been used on a media with a media_id and this works like a queue.

First I reserve a media row

```
UPDATE media SET performed_by = 'worker_id' WHERE performed_by = NULL LIMIT 1
```

Then I want to fetch the media row with the corresponding media_resources_used info

```
SELECT * FROM media AS me INNER JOIN media_resources_used AS au ON me.media_id = au.media_id WHERE me.performed_by = 'worker_id'
```

But this takes around 20 seconds to complete.

EXPLAIN shows

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys |     key      | key_len |  ref  |  rows   |                      Extra                      |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | me    | ref  | performed_by  | performed_by | 63      | const |       1 | Using index condition                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | au    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  | 1439398 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

And it seems the index at media_id isn't even used.

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE performed_by = 'worker_id'
SELECT * FROM media_resources_used WHERE media_id = '$media_id_from_above'
```

separated they both execute under 0.001 seconds.

What could be the issue there?

Comment: An index on `(performed_by, media_id)` would help. But I fear that the two `media_id` columns - having different type/collation - will be a performance issue anyway.

Comment: (Irrelevant to the question) but you have 2 identical indexes on `media (mid)` and 2 indexes on `media_resources_used (media_id)`. You only need one of each.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE  `media` ADD INDEX  `performed_by_media_id` (  `performed_by` ,  `media_id` );` Didn't improve query performance at all. I changed both media_ids to VARCHAR(50) now

Comment: Make sure they have the same CHARSET. One has `utf8` and the other `latin1` (and take a backup of the table before you make any changes like that.)

Comment: Which version of MariaDB do you use?

Comment: And do you really have `WHERE performed_by = NULL` there? It should be `WHERE performed_by IS NULL`, otherwise no row will be updated.

Comment: If `media_id` is interger type then you should have the data type as `int` in both the tables and more over the `COLLATE` on the first table for the `media_id` should be removed.

Comment: I'm using `MariaDB 10.0.20`. I shrunk the tables here for better understanding and therefore I couldn't leave the update query as it was but yes, it's `WHERE performed_by IS NULL`, thanks for mentioning it. `media_id` is a string like `9879696_87687687_98698696` mostly int but it has `_` in between. I've changed media_accounts_used to `utf8_unicode_ci` and the query now seems to run fast under 0.000x seconds. Could it really be just that CHARSET?

Comment: @maddo7 yes, if fields types do not match, some type conversions have to take place, that may happen with charset/collation and it does the same as using a function on the column - direct index access is not possible anymore

Answer (score -1):

Change the line

UNIQUE KEY `media_id` (`user`,`media_id`)

to

UNIQUE KEY `media_id` (`media_id`)

then execute the query it will perform better